# MySQLi prepare with fetch_assoc, or is mysql_real_escape_string ok to use?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I inherited a moderately large sized code base that makes extensive use of mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_fetch_object, and doesn't have any security precautions preventing SQL injection. I decided that this was a Very Bad Thing<sup>TM</sup> that needed fixing.

Initially, I intended on moving to mysqli prepare/bind_param/execute statements to handle DB queries. However, the following does not work:

```
$stmt = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();

// Somehow retrieve the fetched row as an object (Doesn't work!)
return $stmt->fetch_assoc();
```

Question 1: Is there a way to use fetch_assoc or fetch_object using prepare/bind? I *can* refactor all the code, but it would be messy and take a very long time.

Question 2: If it is not possible to do this, is it just as effective from a security standpoint to use mysqli_query(), provided all inputs are properly escaped via mysql_real_escape_string()? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`  Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
2. You can use mysqli if you want. As long as you use the real_escape_string functions on ALL user data (including your own) that's going into SQL statements, then it's no less secure than using prepared statements - it's just much easier to miss a post and leave a hole open.

Comment: It looks like to do that, I'll have to use PDO instead of mysqli, but I think that should be fine.

Comment: There is `$result = $stmt->get_result()` for mysqli, which should return a regular result set you can do a while(fetchrow()) type thing on, but I've never used it, so not sure if that's exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Replacing raw mysql with raw mysli makes very little sense.
in fact, all those doleful repetitive prepare/bind/execute/fetch being as ugly as mysql_query/fetch.

If you going to refactor your code anyway,  you have to develop some *library* function, which will take a query and it's prameters as arguments and return an array of data, doing all the fetching inside.

as for the escaping all inputs via mysql_real_escape_string(), it is going to be an equivalent of magic quotes, which, at last, been acknowledged as a bad practice.

in fact, mysql_real_escape_string() doesnt make any data safe. it has nothing to do with safety at all. it's merely a formatting routine, and works only for strings. But there are other types to insert into query. For the detailed explanations refer to my prefious answer, [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement)